# Simple yes/no loop to repeat/end - MIPS assembly (MARS)

Tags: loops, assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

bI'm not so sure why it's not reading the input and deciding to repeat or end.. Here is my code, help would be appreciated!

```
.data  
again:
    .asciiz "Again (y or n)? "  
answer:
    .asciiz " "  

.text  
.globl main  
  main:
    li  $v0, 4  
    la  $a0, again  
    syscall  

    la  $s4, answer
    jal get 

    beq $v0, 'y', main
    beq $v0, 'Y', main

    li  $v0, 10 
    syscall 

  get:  
    li  $v0, 12  
    li      $a1, 2  
    syscall  
    jr  $ra
```

Comment: Not familiar with MARS, but `sw  $v0, ($s4)`, does $v0 really contain the character and not a _pointer_ to the character? I think you may need to do an `LB`/`SB` instead to store the character into `answer`.

Comment: sw  $v0, ($s4) ==> store word: store $v0 contents into effective word memory address

Comment: Yes, but do you really want to store the _pointer_ to the `Y` that is entered into `answer`? Looks like you're trying to read it as a character later. I'm assuming the syscall `read string` returns a pointer to the string, not the value of the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
.data
again:
    .asciiz "Again (y or n)? "  
answer:
    .space 256

.text  
.globl main  
  main:
    li  $v0, 4  
    la  $a0, again  
    syscall  

    la  $a0, answer
    li  $a1, 3
    li  $v0, 8
    syscall

    lb  $t4, 0($a0)

    beq $t4, 'y', main
    beq $t4, 'Y', main

    li  $v0, 10 
    syscall
```

Firstly, in your code, you seem to misunderstand the way the syscalls work and how they ought to interact with functions ([some docs here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html)). Because your get routine basically just called a syscall, I took it out as adding a routine for something that basic is probably adding complexity rather than reducing it.

Next, the main problem of your code was a misunderstanding of the way input buffering works. In your code, you allocated exactly 2 bytes of space for `answer`, and then use syscalls to get no more than 2 bytes at a time. This will not work for `stdin`, because on most systems, `stdin` is line buffered, meaning that the user must press `ENTER` in order to flush the stream. This means that when the user types `'y'`, a `syscall` actually returns `"y\n\0"`.

To fix this I expanded the `syscall` to read 3 characters and answer to store up to 256. Expanding this to be safe for any size is an excersize left to the reader.

Comment: I think I figured out how to do it as well with my revised code^ . Think I get the register contents and the addresses mixed up.